# Set the minimum grid resolution in AChartEngine?

Tags: achartengine

I am using AchartEngine library to plot the measurements from a sensor.  The values are in the order of 1E-6.

When I try to plot the values they are shown correctly but as I zoom the plot, the maximum resolution I can see in the x Labels is in the order of 1E-4. I am using following code to change the number of labels:

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(20);
mRenderer.setYLabels(20);
```

I am also changing the range of the y axis, but the resolution remains unchanged. Has anyone found this problem before?

EDIT

I do not have enough reputation to post images, but the following link shows the chartview that I am getting.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49921111/measurement1.png

What I want is to have more grid lines between 3.0E-5 and 4.0E-5. Unfortunately I have not found how to do that. I also tried changing the renderer pan, initial range of the plot and zoom limits. all without sucess. I was thinking the only option left would be to override some of the draw methods but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Try using setPanLimits() method .

Comment: I have tried using the setPanLimits(), i set it to very small values. but still it does not have an effect on the resolution. Also the grid is supposed to be aproximattely 20 lines when i use mRenderer.setXLabels(20), but when showing very small values i see only one grid line.

Comment: Post some screenshots such as we understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I Have digged into the source code of AChartEngine and found the problem that it has when small numbers are to be plotted. It is in a static function used to draw labels by every chart:

```
private static double[] computeLabels(final double start, final double end,
final int approxNumLabels) {
// The problem is right here in this condition.
if (Math.abs(start - end) < 0.000001f) {
  return new double[] { start, start, 0 };
}
double s = start;
double e = end;
boolean switched = false;
if (s > e) {
switched = true;
double tmp = s;
s = e;
e = tmp;
}
double xStep = roundUp(Math.abs(s - e) / approxNumLabels);
// Compute x starting point so it is a multiple of xStep.
double xStart = xStep * Math.ceil(s / xStep);
double xEnd = xStep * Math.floor(e / xStep);
if (switched) {
return new double[] { xEnd, xStart, -1.0 * xStep };
}
return new double[] { xStart, xEnd, xStep };
}
```

So this function basically takes the start (minimum) and and end (maximum) values of the plot and the aproximate number of labels. Then it rounds the values and computes the step of the grid (xStep). If the difference between start and end is too small (0.000001f) then the start and end are the same and the step is 0. That is why its not showing any labels in between this small values nor any grid lines!. So I just need to change the 0.000001f with a smaller number or with a variable in order to control the resolution of the grid. I hope this can help someone.